# Secure communication between two apps

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I have two applications, could be or could not be on the same server. Now I need to transfer some data/**form data** to and fro. Like user data.

Is there any existing technique/way to do a secure communication. I want to be sure if the request came from my app.

Please help me with the simplest implementation.

FYI i am using Angular App as App1 and Node as App2 and both share same DB. I am using Post and Get requests for making the api calls.

Comment: Could you please describe more specifically what kind of information you want to transfer from one app to another? Some example maybe?

Comment: just some form data